# php doing wrong replace in str_replace function

Tags: php

Well i code a php function for multiple string replacement

```
$searchArray = array("0","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","z","x","y","w","u","v","j","i","h","g","f","e","d","c","b","a");
$replaceArray = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");       
$string='protect your php code';
echo $code=str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $string);
```

its result = protvxt moor psp xowv which seem correct

well when i reverse its position

```
$string='protvxt moor psp xowv';       
$searchArray = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");   

$replaceArray = array("0","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","z","x","y","w","u","v","j","i","h","g","f","e","d","c","b","a");
echo $code=str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $string);
```

it give me this answer  = eifgecg bffi ehe cfde (which is wrong) it should correctly reversed and gives answer protect your php code

Honestly i have no idea why php doing this wrong

i paste above code here

```
http://codepad.org/xbSCieZl
```

please check this i want to know what i doing wrong it makes me mad

Comment: Key to the issue is that not all letters are coded, but even you decode it back, you decode even letters which weren't encoded.

Comment: Not sure what you try to do and what result you expect but check search and replace arrays and character position in each array. For example in code above 0 is replaced with 1, 9 with 2 etc. Also array should be the same length

Comment: If you're only doing single character-for-character substitutions, [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr) might be more appropriate than `str_replace()`. ([codepad example](http://codepad.org/KkjVrahZ))

Comment: This *will not work* in general.  You got lucky with your test string.  If you try to encode the string "123" you will get "123", because the 1 is changed to a zero and then later on the zero is changed to a 1, et cetera.  See the [str_replace gotchas](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: HI  Wiseguy i try your code but no success http://codepad.org/T0xbGXOP

Comment: Using `strtr()` does not inherently fix the logic problem you have which others have already pointed out. That's why I made a comment, not an answer. Fix that first. After that, I recommend using `strtr()` instead of `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays should contain the same chars.

the first conversion doesn't change the characters 'pro' from 'protect'

but the reversing does.

edit:
sorry this answer is wrong due to the following gotcha that I was unaware of, James mentioned above: "This will not work in general. You got lucky with your test string. If you try to encode the string "123" you will get "123", because the 1 is changed to a zero and then later on the zero is changed to a 1, et cetera. See the str_replace gotchas –  James"

You can use the suggestion above strtr()

```
$search = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$replace = "zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy"; 

$string='protect your php code';

echo $code=strtr($string, $search, $replace);   
echo '<br>';    
echo strtr($code, $replace, $search);
```

output:
oqnsdbs xntq ogo bncd
protect your php code

edit:
additionally you can generate your string and randomize:

```
$search = implode("",range("a","z")).implode("",range("0","9"));
$replace = str_shuffle($search);
```

http://codepad.org/DZJRp9Zx

Comment: my array length is correct if 36 letter is search array then 36 letter in replace array

Comment: another blender : 12345 change into  +)(*&    when i try to reverse it gives me klmno what a lame language not able to handle basic function